# Qt OS X hiding MainWindow freezes GUI

Tags: c++, qt

I've found that when pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on my Mac and then tabbing back into the application my GUI is frozen until i minimize and maximize the window.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

I've tried:

- Removing `QTimer`
- Removing `eventFilter`

I'm out of ideas on what to try here.

**Edit**

I tried to create a new simply application that just contained a form and a text input. I deployed it using `macdeployqt` and I get the exact same behavior. The GUI freezes after a hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Can't confirm this. Tested on OSx Mountain Lion with Qt 5.2.1

Comment: Im running OS X 10.6.8 and Qt 5.2.1

Comment: Is your Software somewhere available?

Comment: Strange thing is it does not happend on my iMac (10.9.2) only on my 10.6.8 Macbook Pro